# How to deal with `unable to fetch schema` error when importing csv of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: import, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I use `import-csv` to import file in Apache IoTDB, a 301 error was reported twice, and the message is `unable to fetch schema`. The export version is 0.13.2 and the import version is 1.2.1. I created an empty database and the schema is automatically created, so there should be no problem with the schema. I also checked the naming format, and there should be no conflicts due to version upgrade. Then how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no special circumstances in time series naming, you can try copying part of the tsfiles in Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 and directly use `load` command to load them into Version 1.2.